# Is the xpath can parse the html content including <br>?

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets, xml-parsing

I want to get the HTML content of article section.

[image]

The content like this.

As below,I want to get the value including `<br>`.

[image]

The parsing formula like this:

`=importxml("https://novel.com","//*[@class='plhin']//td[@class='t_f']")`

And I get the data as below.
There is some empty value on it.

[image]

On the other way,I use a simpler expression.

It can get the better arrangement.

But there isn't `<br>` elements,neither.

`=importxml("https://novel.com","//*[@class='plhin']")`

[image]

Is there some syntax can retrieve the result including `<br>` elements?

Thank you.

Comment: You may be able to do this with BeautifulSoup, but if you're interested, you'll have to post more of the actual html (not a picture) and an example of your desired output.